# How to get the correct date by using dateformatter method?

Tags: ios, xcode4.2, nsdateformatter

here is my code:

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setDateStyle:NSDateFormatterMediumStyle];
[dateFormatter setTimeStyle:NSDateFormatterNoStyle];

NSDate *date = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceReferenceDate:1275822000000+0000];
```

// the string is json parsing string

```
NSString *formattedDateString = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:date];
NSLog(@"formattedDateString: %@", formattedDateString);
```

The output is Dec 20,5828963

But my required output is June 6,2010

How to change my code for correct output?

Comment: just a little tip; you should explain what you are trying to achieve in a more general way added to your example :) easier to understand

Comment: There must be something wrong with you 12758220000000000. From where did you get that value ?

Comment: date formatter is working fine, 12758220000000000 is wrong number - what does it mean and where it came from?

Comment: @StianStorrvik hi friend i pass the string to NSdate object and i think it converts date but the output is wrong.in jave this string executes june 6,2010.but output is Dec 20,5828963

Comment: Where did you get that number? Because it seems so high, Dec 20,5828963 seems correct.

Comment: Your nsdate is itself giving wrong output .1st research and then ask question...the number you have given takes the date in negative..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to receive June 6, 2010 from some magic number then use this:

```
NSDate *date = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceReferenceDate:297475822];
```

For some reason your number is very big, and as @wrock mentioned it multiplies on 10 million, so for getting correct value you can use dateWithTimeIntervalSince1970 and divide it on 10 million

```
NSDate *date = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSince1970:1275822000];
```

Comment: Exactly. `dateWithTimeIntervalSinceReferenceDate:` accepts the number of seconds since 1 January 2001 GMT. 12758220000000000 seconds is a very long time.

Comment: oh friend it's an service string.How can i change

Comment: It seems like a Unix timestamp multiplied ten million. Use `[NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceReferenceDate:(whatYourServiceGaveYou*1.0e-7-NSTimeIntervalSince1970)]`

Comment: Yep, 1275822000 is a true number for using `dateWithTimeIntervalSince1970` method

Comment: @beryllium thanks for pointing out, I totally forgot about that message.

Answer (score 2):

First: your timestamp seems like a Java timestamp, but it has a few extra zeros (4 of them exactly). You have to convert this to a Unix timestamp, which is the number of seconds since the Unix epoch (as opposed to Java, which is the number of milliseconds since the Unix epoch).

`dateWithTimeIntervalSinceReferenceDate:` doesn't accept Unix timestamps, but the conversion is easy:

```
double timestampFromService = 12758220000000000;
NSDate *date = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSince1970:
    (timestampFromService*1.0e-7)];
```

Answer (score 0):

Use date in readable manner :

```
NSDate *myDate = [NSDate dateWithString:@"2010-06-06 00:00:00"];

NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setDateStyle:NSDateFormatterMediumStyle];
[dateFormatter setTimeStyle:NSDateFormatterNoStyle];

NSString *formattedDateString = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:myDate];
NSLog(@"formattedDateString: %@", formattedDateString);
```

Comment: but my string is @"12758220000000000"

Comment: So your string is incorrect. This is not jun 06 2010.Your code is fine.